# What is the relationship between a strong work ethic and an honest reputation and individual success?

Tags: social-psychology, measurement, mathematical-psychology, economics, behavioral-economics

We're all being constantly told that strong work ethics, honestly reputation and all similar things is the key and the only key to success. But observation of success of certain politicians, marketing companies and even some colleagues in an office casts doubts on this alleged correlation.

"[Honesty and beliefs about honesty in 15 countries](https://www.uea.ac.uk/documents/3154295/7054672/Honesty+paper/41fecf09-235e-45c1-afc2-b872ea0ac882)" by DavidHugh-Jones shows relation between population honestly and economy growth which is of much less doubt but what would be much more interesting is to see correlation between individual's honesty and individual's success. From the [highlights on ScienceDirect](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S016726811630052X):

> - Average honesty of resident nationals of 15 countries was measured in two experiments.
> - There are large cross-country differences in honesty.
> - Honesty correlates at country level with GDP and Protestantism.
> - Participants’ expectations about honesty in different countries were also elicited.
> - Expectations were not correlated to reality, but driven by cognitive biases.

Is there an scientific social experiment supporting this or indeed the opposite?

Comment: You should summarize the conclusions of the linked research in your question. Also, define "success", as it means different things to different people.